# jquery file upload without redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know that I cannot upload a file with jquery so I come up with this solution:

```
    var ifframe = $("<iframe></iframe>");
    var input = $('<input type="file" id="file" name="file" size="10"/>');
    var form = $('<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form> ');
    form.append(input);
    ifframe.append(form);
    input.change(function(){
        form.submit();
    }
    );
    input.trigger("click");
```

Basically I try to create a form insde the iframe and the trigger a click on the file field so the user is given a window where he can select image. then the form is automatically submitted and the main page does not get redirected since the form is in an iframe. The problem is that the main page does get redirected. Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: You could take a look at this. I believe you'll find it to be a simpler solution :http://digipiph.com/blog/submitting-multipartform-data-using-jquery-and-ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, JQ can submit a form w. attachment asynchronously. Take a look at this example. Much better than an iframe approach.

```
 $("#addProductForm").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //grab all form data  
    var formData = $(this).serialize();

 $.ajax({
        url: 'addProduct.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (returndata) {
        $("#productFormOutput").html(returndata);
        alert(formData);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("error in ajax form submission");
            }
    });

    return false;
    });
```